# Google Maps Pass value of dragend to variable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, draggable

Ok I spent 2 days working on this time for some help :) Everything works fine with the code now I just need to make the marker draggable and update Lat and Lng values.  At present the code captures lat and lng via current position as well as via entering a location on the web page. The value of _Lat and _lng are then submitted the a database.   I need the user to be able to drag the marker to fine tune the location and update _lat and _lng prior to the database submit.  I have made the marker draggable but I can't figure out how to add the dragend code so that it dynamically updates the value of lat and _lng prior to the database submit. I don't need to update anything on the web page just I need to update the _lat and _lng values that get posted to the database.  Here is the existing code:

### Thanks

```
var gmap;
var gmarker;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
    // Get here center of map - by default - San Francisco center
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.47, -122.25);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: center,
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    // Set inner position of map to form parameters
    $('input[name="_lat"]').val(37.47);
    $('input[name="_lng"]').val(-122.25);

    gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: gmap,
            position: center,
            icon: '/static/internal/images/mapicon.png',
    draggable: true
        });





    google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'click', function(event) {
        gmarker.setPosition(event.latLng);
        $('input[name="_lat"]').val(event.latLng.lat());
        $('input[name="_lng"]').val(event.latLng.lng());
    });


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var _lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var _lat = position.coords.latitude;
            $('input[name="_lng"]').val(_lng);
            $('input[name="_lat"]').val(_lat);
            var new_position = new google.maps.LatLng(_lat, _lng);
            gmap.setCenter(new_position);
            gmarker.setPosition(new_position);
        })
}

function showAddress(address) {
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode(
      {'address': address},
      function(results, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
          gmap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          gmarker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
          $('input[name="_lat"]').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
          $('input[name="_lng"]').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David but that part of the code works fine. I'm a beginner here someone else coded the existing code and it works fine.  Right now when you first open the page it captures you existing location and populates the lat and lng just fine.  Also, on the web page you can manually enter a location and it does a lookup for lat and lng and that all works just fine.

The user then uploads photos that get tagged with the lat and Lng values.

Comment: It am trying to add some functionality to the code by making the marker draggable so that my users can fine tune their exaction (when that location is not the same as where they are at when doing the photo upload) location by dragging the marker. I need this to update the lat and lng prior to the user uploading their photos.


I tried adding the code below but its not working:

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'click', function(event) {
            gmarker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            $('input[name="_lat"]').val(event.latLng.lat());
            $('input[name="_lng"]').val(event.latLng.lng());
        });

Thanks again

Comment: i changed that line from gmap to gmarker and it didn't break existing functionality nor did it get the dragged position to update either. I'm not sure if they code does anything at present.

Comment: Your problem must be outwith the code you posted. I have tried both my answer and that of Dr Molle in your code and both update the inputs when marker is moved.With my answer when the marker is moved and clicked. In the other when marker is moving

Answer (score 1):

listen to the `position_changed`-event of the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarker, 'position_changed', function() {

    $('input[name="_lat"]').val(this.getPosition().lat());
    $('input[name="_lng"]').val(this.getPosition().lng());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is on map it should be on marker

Change

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'click', function(event) {
```

To

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarker, 'click', function(event) {
```